# Is Christopher Nolan no longer associated with Batman vs Superman?

Tags: batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, dc-extended-universe

The film credits about cast & crew on IMDb pages no longer show Nolan listed as executive producer. Has Nolan bowed out of the project? Or is there a role change?

Comment: Most probably yes. But it's rumor yet.

Comment: It's still rumor but with Batfleck happening, the official announcement can be far away. http://comicbook.com/blog/2013/08/26/christopher-nolan-rumored-to-have-dropped-out-of-batman-vs-superman-movie/

Comment: Careful with posts like this as it can attract a lot of *speculation* which is not allowed here.

Comment: I am unsure if this tag serve any value because the movie name is not confirm yet.

Comment: IMDB is little more than an unsourced wiki.  The content of future movie pages there matters little.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct.

Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan's brother and *The Dark Knight Rises* screenwriter, gave an interview to [Coming Soon](http://www.comingsoon.net/news/movienews.php?id=124410) where he said:

> I love those guys and my brother was involved in ‘Man of Steel’ with
>   Zack [Snyder] and David [Goyer]. I kind of feel like that chapter for
>   us is closed. To be continued somewhere farther down the line? Maybe.

Whilst neither brother has given an interview explicitly stating *why* they've chosen to leave the projects, it doesn't appear like they were forced out - rather, it seems they left to pursue other projects.

Comment: Personally, I feel BvS was just not up to the mark of other films like Dark Knight. Maybe Nolan noticed this and withdrew.

Answer (score 0):

In Batman Vs Superman Christopher Nolan and Emma Thomas will be executive producers, along with Benjamin Melniker and Michael E. Uslan.

Charles Roven and Deborah Snyder will be producers.

source - http://henrycavill.org/en/filmography/projects/man-of-steel-2

Comment: As @kicker86 notes in his question, IMDb no longer lists Nolan (or Thomas) as executive producers. Your link is from July 20.

Answer (score 0):

Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice no longer lists *Christopher Nolan* as *Executive Producer* in multiple press releases since the initial announcement of the movie. Instead, the title of executive producer is being given to Benjamin Melniker, Michael E. Uslan, Wesley Coller, David S. Goyer and Geoff Johns. As stated by [this press release by Warner Brothers featured on Businesswire](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20140131005753/en/Jesse-Eisenberg-Jeremy-Irons-Join-Cast-Warner)